# Blazor Server Side IIS Hosting Issue

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

Pulling my hair out trying to set up a Blazor Server Side application on IIS.

I've already installed the application on one test server without too much difficulty however I've now run into difficulty deploying to the client's server.

To ensure the issue wasn't with my application I tested using the Blazor Server-Side template and the same issue is found.

If I open Microsoft Edge on the server and browse to the URL of the application everything works perfectly

[image: Blazor Application on Server]

However, if I browse to the same URL on my local Edge browser I get a redirect from https://portal... to the servers IP address https://172.16... and then a timeout.

[image: Blazor Application on Local Browser]

Could this be caused by a firewall setting blocking something that Blazor requires or a DNS issue?

Note that if I just have the website pointing to a simple website then it works fine both on the server and on my local browser.

Comment: Redirection can only come from IIS or your Blazor app, so tracing that down with tools like Fiddler and IIS Failed Request Tracing are necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried my best to examine Fiddler and IIS Failed Request Tracing logs however it hasn't led me to identify the cause. I'm going to contact the client IT to see if there are any firewall rules or similar that could be interfering.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no redirection in the Blazor Server Side application. Do you have registered DNS? This problem may be caused by caching. you can clear the cache in Edge and try again.

Comment: Thanks. Tried clearing cache however issue remains. I've noticed that if in the site bindings I only have an HTTPS entry the website works fine on the server's browser but on my local browser I get 503 Service Unavailable. I've checked all the common issues associated with a 503 error but no joy.

Surprisingly if I only have an HTTP binding then the Blazor app will load fine on my local browser and will even connect using either HTTP or HTTPS. On the server's browser I receive the message ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was unrelated to Blazor and was instead caused by Firewall settings.